# Bootstrap-selectpicker to a default value without using JS or jQuery

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm mixing HTML and C# and I want to set the default selected value from a selectpicker.
As I load a lot of data that contain each a selectpicker, I need to select the right option directly when the page is loading and not afterwards which will cost me time (using document ready, trigger the selection for each of the data showed).

Here's what I'm trying for the moment:

```
<select id="PayStatus" data-key="@item.CandidateId" class="selectpicker gw-bs-small w-100">
  <option value="0" selected=@(item.PaymentStatus == 0 ? "selected" : "") data-content="<span class='badge badge-red-dark-500 text-white label-important'><i class='icon-cross mr-1'></i>InvoiceOpen</span>"></option>
  <option value="1" selected=@(item.PaymentStatus == 1 ? "selected" : "") data-content="<span class='badge badge-byline-300 text-green'>FreeDevelopment</span>">FreeDevelopment</option>
  <option value="2" selected=@(item.PaymentStatus == 2 ? "selected" : "") data-content="<span class='badge badge-green-500 text-white'><i class='icon-check mr-></i></span>
</select>
```

As you can see I try to make it work with this: `selected=@(item.PaymentStatus == 2 ? "selected" : "")` but the value returned true but it's not selected, it's always the first option that is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of empty string, use null:

```
 <select id="PayStatus" data-key="@item.CandidateId" class="selectpicker gw-bs-small w-100">
     <option value="0" selected=@(item.PaymentStatus == 0 ? "selected" : null) data-content="<span class='badge badge-red-dark-500 text-white label-important'><i class='icon-cross mr-1'></i>InvoiceOpen</span>"></option>
     <option value="1" selected=@(item.PaymentStatus == 1 ? "selected" : null) data-content="<span class='badge badge-byline-300 text-green'>FreeDevelopment</span>">FreeDevelopment</option>
     <option value="2" selected=@(item.PaymentStatus == 2 ? "selected" : null) data-content="<span class='badge badge-green-500 text-white'><i class='icon-check mr-1'></i>InvoicePaid</span>">InvoicePaid</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you only need the `selected` not `selected="selected"` or `selected="true"` in your `<option>` to actually make it selected.
You should try:

```
 <select id="PayStatus" data-key="@item.CandidateId" class="selectpicker gw-bs-small w-100">
     <option value="0" @(item.PaymentStatus == 0 ? "selected" : "") data-content="<span class='badge badge-red-dark-500 text-white label-important'><i class='icon-cross mr-1'></i>InvoiceOpen</span>"></option>
     <option value="1" @(item.PaymentStatus == 1 ? "selected" : "") data-content="<span class='badge badge-byline-300 text-green'>FreeDevelopment</span>">FreeDevelopment</option>
     <option value="2" @(item.PaymentStatus == 2 ? "selected" : "") data-content="<span class='badge badge-green-500 text-white'><i class='icon-check mr-1'></i>InvoicePaid</span>">InvoicePaid</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: This won't work as it's not a regular select dropdown but a bootstrap selectpicker

Comment: Just tested it with the latest bootstrap-select (1.13.14) and its working fine with the exact above code. Why you think it would not work?

Comment: I don't remember but I had errors directly related to the option tag saying something like it doesn't get what I try to do with `@(item.PaymentStatus == 0 ? "selected" : "")`